# Bitmap not scaling to imageView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, bitmap

I do not fully understand where my problem lies, so I will provide as much information as I can, some of it may be irrelevant to finding the answer but some of it may help.

**The problem**

I have integrated a camera into my application, I am using a **surfaceView** to show a preview of the camera, when capturing the image I **take the raw image bytes** and send them through an ObjectOutput stream where I will show the image on that said activity. Here is a snippet of that code:

```
out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(getActivity().getCacheDir(),"")+"cacheFile.srl"));
out.writeObject(bytes);
```

In the other activity I read in the bytes and show the image:

```
bytes = (byte[]) in.readObject();
image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
myHolder.setImageBitmap(image);
```

Here is my XML file for the activity which shows the image:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragments.Home">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:id="@+id/ih"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

[Here is the problem, I need to scale the image to fit the whole activity, yet there is white lines on either side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5JEE.jpg)

If any other information is needed please let me know and ill update the post

Update 1

I changed my layout to this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/ih"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"/>
```

yet I still have the white lines either side

Comment: read about  `ImageView`'s `scaleType`s

Comment: Please can you share the resolution of the image and your device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` as attribute for the `ImageView` if you want the image to fit its bounds and cut of the rest

You can find more informations about scaletypes here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: I updated my post, I tried what you said it didnt work, look at the update in original post

Comment: Try setting android:adjustViewBounds="true" maybe this helps